# When keyboard is up, scrollview gettings scrolled when scrollview is zoomed eventhough I dont change the contentOffset

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

When the keyboard is up, the scrollview's X position getting shifted automatically if the scrolliew is already zoomed. I didnt change the contentOffset. But still the scrollview is shifting when keyboard up.

I never changed the contentOffset or any other scrollview position but scrollview shifting itself to another X position.

Comment: Scroll view's content offset method is called though I have commented out all the content offset code. This happens only when the keyboard is up while image view is zoomed